# How to rename Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I just downloaded Visual Studio and the name is showing like this "Visual Studio Community 2017 (2)". Everything is working but that "2" at the end is just annoying. And of course first thing I've tried was reinstalling. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2nv6.png)

And by the way my computer is completely new and I've never had Visual Studio installed on this computer.

Comment: I've seen the same and my theory then was that the build tools you've already installed somehow counts as the first instance of Visual Studio 2017 that you have installed, and you're now installing the second instance. You can have multiple hives or whatnot of installation. I know nothing more than what I already wrote here so it's just a theory, but perhaps it sparks some ideas for someone who knows more about this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The issue is that the instance of visual studio has a nickname associated with it. Use the following instructions to change the nickname of an existing Visual Studio (tested with VS2017) installation (partially lifted from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99059/not-able-to-easiliy-change-installation-nickname.html):

> 1. Set the nickname in the *.isolation.ini files in
>    %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual
>    Studio\2017\[Version]\Common7\IDE.
> 2. Set the nickname in the state.json file in
>    %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances\[InstanceId]\state.json
> 3. Open regedit, go to under path
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, find there "Visual Studio {your version} 2017 (2)" (The folder will have a different name use the regedit search with "(2)" to find the corresponding entry. Rename string to be without " (2)" - this will change application name appearance in control panel / program and features.

You'll need admin permission to modify these files. If you want to remove the nickname altogether, just set it to an empty string (e.g. `Nickname=` in the .ini files, `"nickname": ""` in the .json).

Note that this will only have affect within VS tools, such as the VS installer in the screenshot you posted. Any names with the suffix in, for example, the Start/Windows menu will need to be renamed manually.

Comment: Same for VS2019, resolved with another answer, just like yours https://superuser.com/questions/1458278/how-do-you-rename-an-installed-application-in-windows-10, thanks your all!

Comment: Works fine for VS2022 also

Comment: I tried for the VS2022 but can't find regedit records. Is name different in regedit?
**Update**
I found it 0748d760 named folder

Comment: @officialmmt Mine had a different number, but it was the shortest non-GUID that didn't plainly spell out what it was.

Comment: If you are having trouble finding it like I was, you can also use `Find...` by right clicking on the `Uninstall` folder(?) in `regedit`. For me, I just put `(2)` which took me straight to the offending nickname. If that doesn't work, a more specific value like `Visual Studio Community 2022 (2)` may work also.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to mess up with any files on you file system, one alternative is to reinstall the product.

After you uninstall the annoying product with the nickname "(2)", you can select the Installation locations tab and specify another nickname or perhaps leave it blank. Mine does not allow to leave it blank.

Here is a screen:

[image]

Comment: You are 2 years late. By the way I reinstalled Windows since then so it's not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If the installer says that a nickname is mandatory, even after uninstalling Visual Studio (like in the screenshot by Bernardo above), you can try the InstallCleanup.exe tool by Microsoft. You can find it in your Visual Studio Installer folder.

After running this tool with the -i flag, I was able to re-install Visual Studio 2019 without a nickname.
[Link to InstallCleanup.exe docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#remove-all-with-installcleanupexe)

Answer (score 1):

A nickname is mandatory for the Visual Studio installation when you are installing the same version of Visual Studio(eg.: VS 2019 or 2022) but with different editions(eg.: VS Community or Professional or Enterprise).

If we uninstall the same version of VS with different edition, then the VS Installer is not asking for the nickname and not taking the nickname as 2, the "Installation nickname" textbox is not visible under Installation locations tab in VS Installer.